# icon link not clickable on mobile

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, icons

I'm having some links on my site which are displayed using FontAwesome icons. However, on mobile devices (tested Chrome and FF) I can't "click" them. They simply seem to have no function, though working on desktop browsers.

Did I miss something?

I use the following code:

```
<span class="side">
<ul>
    <li><a href="blaaa1"><i class="fa fa-print"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="blaaa2"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="blaaa3"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

```
.side a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You can take a look here: http://mydivision.net/
I'm talking about the links on the right side of each blog post image (printer, envelope and link icon).

Answer (score 1):

The printer works fine for me.

Try using a span, it might work.